# jquery: dynamically add event for overlay window

Tags: jquery

i have a problem i could not solve albeit i read all the possible solutions to similar questions
i have an ajax request that, on success, adds dinamically a row to a table
inside, i have to put a link that shows an overlay window.

this is the html 'static' code:

```
<tr valign="top" id="trc_0">
<td><strong><em>Principal Investigator</em></strong></td>
<td><span id="cName_0">Georg Wohlfahrt</span></td>
<td><span id="cInst_0">University of Innsbruck</span></td>
<td><span id="cMail_0">georg.wohlfahrt@uibk.ac.at</span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="ifch_0" disabled="disabled"  /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="ibch_0" disabled="disabled"  /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="iach_0" disabled="disabled"  /></td>
<td><a href='#' onclick='deleteColl(518,0 );'>Delete</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" class='modalInput' rel='#pi_colls' id='edit_coll_0' onclick='collMe( 0 , "A",518);' Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

and here is the jquery code that adds the row

```
trToAdd="<tr id='trc_"+collToSend+"'><td>Collaborator</td>";
trToAdd+="<td><span id='cName_"+collToSend+"'>"+$("#collNamex").val()+"</span></td>";
trToAdd+="<td><span id='cInst_"+collToSend+"'>"+$("#collInstx").val()+"</span></td>";
trToAdd+="<td><span id='cMail_"+collToSend+"'>"+$("#collMailx").val()+"</span></td>";
trToAdd+="<td>"+inputF+"</td>";
trToAdd+="<td>"+inputB+"</td>";
trToAdd+="<td>"+inputA+"</td>";
trToAdd+="<td><a href='#' class='modalInput' rel='#pi_colls'>Edit</a></td>";
trToAdd+="</tr>";
$('#collTab tr:last').after(trToAdd);
```

the row is correclty inserted, but the event that should show the overlay window doesn't work

finally, i post the html and javascript for the overaly:

```
<div class="modal" id="pi_colls">
<h2>This is a PI dialog</h2>
<table>
<tr><td>Coll type</td><td>PI: <input type="checkbox" id="pix" />Coll: <input type="checkbox" id="collx"  /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" id="collNamex" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Institution</td><td><input type="text" id="collInstx" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mail</td><td><input type="text" id="collMailx" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Type</td><td>Anc: <input type="checkbox" id="collAncx" />Bio: <input type="checkbox" id="collBiox"  /><br />Flu:<input type="checkbox" id="collFlux"  /></td>      </tr>
 </table>

<p>
<a href="#" class="close" onclick="saveColl();">Yes</a>
<a href="#" class="close">No</a>
 </p>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {

    var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({

        mask: {
            color: '#ebecff',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.9
        },

        closeOnClick: false
    });

 });
</script>
```

hope i have been clear...can anyone help me?
thanx
diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delegate the event:

```
$('#idofTable').delegate('a.modalInput', 'click', function() {

    $(".modalInput").overlay({

        mask: {
            color: '#ebecff',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.9
        },

        closeOnClick: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response
there is a slight improvement.
the problem is that the click event on the added row is fired only after the second click
this is the [link](http://www.bitmorphosi.it/overlay) to a very simplified page, without any server functions.
you can view the whole code behind of the page, as it's pure html+javascript

thanks
Diego